# Capture specific rows of a ListObject to an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, rows, listobject

I need help trying to figure out something I haven't done before in Excel VBA.  I'm trying to assign specific (consecutive) rows of a listobject to an array.  Is this possible?

Previously I was using code to copy over the entire table into the array, which worked, but it would capture unused blank rows I didn't want included.  I was able to get some FUNCTIONS up and running which capture the first and low filled row numbers of the listobject for reference, but I cannot figure out how to assign ONLY this range of rows from the listobject into the array

This, for instance, works to assign only the 1st row:
**varESInvoiceBreakdown = PrimeLO.ListRows(1).Range.Value**

However, this doesn't work to capture the first two rows.  I get an error
**varESInvoiceBreakdown = PrimeLO.ListRows("1:2").Range.Value**

Even though it indicates in a segment of this article that you can reference multiple rows in this manner
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

I was hoping to reference the two integer variables I have setup for the row selection.

Sincerely,
Kris

Comment: Refering to filtering the table, pasting the values elsewhere, then copying that range into the array and deleting it?

Comment: Is there no way to just reference the listobject data from specific (multiple) rows directly without those workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't index into the `ListRows` collection like that. Use `DataBodyRange.Rows`.

```
varESInvoiceBreakdown = PrimeLO.DataBodyRange.Rows("1:2").Value
```

With variables:

```
Dim startRow as Long
Dim endRow as Long

startRow = 1
endRow = 2

varESInvoiceBreakdown = PrimeLO.DataBodyRange.Rows(startRow & ":" & endRow).Value
```

Comment: Thank you, @BigBen, that did work to select the two rows!  Is it possible to use variables to represent the row numbers in it?